# PHP 3D array count unique values

Tags: php, arrays, count, statistics

I have a 3D array. I need to extract the following:

1. the number of occurrences of unique items in deepest level array
2. the number of co-occurrences of certain items in deepest level array

Array looks like this:

```
$arr = (
       [0] => array([0] => array([flag][token][value])
                    [1] => array([flag][token][value])
                    )
       )
```

I tried looping through the array using a *for* loop and an *if* statement, like this:

```
$new_arr1 = ""; // $new_arr1 = array(); //same thing, the later code doesn't work

for ($i=0; $i<count($arr);$i++)
{
    for ($j=0; $j<count($arr[$i]); $j++)
        {

          $value= $arr[$i][$j][value];

          if ($arr[$i][$j][flag] == "noun")
             array_push($new_arr1, $value)

          elseif ($arr[$i][$j][flag] == "verb")
             array_push($new_arr2, $value)
        }
}
```

did the same thing with *switch* statement, couldn't get it to work. By doing this kind of conditioning I was hoping to get all of the values from the deepest level array that meet the certain criteria into one array, and then perform *array_count_values* on them. That would give me the following:

for *flag* == "noun", value of *value* element stored in $new_arr1, and for *flag* == "verb", value of *value* element stored in $new_arr2:

```
$new_arr1 = (
           [dog] => 7
           [cat] => 2
           [horse] => 4
          );

$new_arr2 = (
           [chase] => 2
           [eat] => 5
           [pwn] => 3
          );
```

this would give me a count of unique values of the deepes level array that I can't access using *array_uniqe* function.

Besides that, I need to perform a count of co-occurrences of these values, something like this:

count the number of times that some token with certain flag comes before or after another token with a certain flag:

*pseudocode:*

```
$count=0;
if ( (($arr[$i][$j][flag] == "noun") && ($arr[$i][$j][value] == "dog")) &&
     (($arr[$i][$j+/-1][flag] == "verb") && ($arr[$i][$j+/-1][value] == "chase"))
   )
$count++;

$counter = array($count = array($arr[$i][$j][value]), $arr[$i][$j+/-1][value])
```

that would basically give the following:

```
counter:
array(
      "7" => ([0] => "dog", [1] => "chase")
      "4" => ([0] => "cat", [1] => "eat")
     )
```

where the "7" and "4" are the names of the associative array, while "dog" and "chase" are the values stored in another array.

```
     )
```

Comment: What is `[flag][token][value]`? Keys? Values? An order of things?

Comment: these are associative keys in an associative array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I follow your question 100%, but something like this might work:

```
$verb_array = array();
$noun_array = array();
foreach($arr as $index => $data){
    if($data['flag'] == 'noun'){
        if(isset($noun_array[$data['value']])){
            $noun_array[$data['value']]++;
        }
        else{
            $noun_array[$data['value']] = 0;
        }
    }
    else if($data['flag'] == 'verb'){
        if(isset($noun_array[$data['value']])){
            $verb_array[$data['value']]++;
        }
        else{
            $verb_array[$data['value']] = 0;
        }            
    }
}
```

Then to get the count of occurrences:

```
$noun_count = count($noun_array);
$verb_count = count($verb_array);
```

And if you need the count of a particular item, it will exist inside of the array.

Comment: thank you very much! :) one step closer to finishing the project :)

Comment: postmortem 6+ years later:
should have used python for this. This was a NLP task, that would have easily been solved using python and nltk.